# Casted timeStamp does not give correct result in PL/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to pl/pgsql and I'm trying to execute following function and it gives 0 records as result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.detectselect (i_channelID integer,te_startTime text,te_endTime text)
RETURNS SETOF detect_inst AS $BODY$
declare
    r detect_inst%rowtype;
    tstz_endTime timestamp without time zone;
    tstz_startTime timestamp without time zone;
BEGIN
    tstz_endTime = to_timestamp(te_endTime,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone;
    tstz_startTime = to_timestamp(te_startTime,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone;
    for r in SELECT * FROM detect_inst d WHERE d."ChannelID" = i_channelID AND d."EndTime" >= tstz_startTime AND d."EndTime" < tstz_endTime loop
        return next r;
    end loop;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

call as

```
select detectselect(1,'2016-01-21 0:0:0','2016-01-23 0:0:0');
```

but it give correct results when i give static time stamp values in this way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.detectselect (i_channelID integer,te_startTime text,te_endTime text)
RETURNS SETOF detect_inst AS $BODY$
declare
    r detect_inst%rowtype;
    tstz_endTime timestamp without time zone;
    tstz_startTime timestamp without time zone;
BEGIN
    tstz_endTime = to_timestamp(te_endTime,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone;
    tstz_startTime = to_timestamp(te_startTime,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone;
    for r in SELECT * FROM detect_inst d WHERE d."ChannelID" = i_channelID AND d."EndTime" >= '2016-01-21 0:0:0' AND d."EndTime" < '2016-01-23 0:0:0' loop
        return next r;
    end loop;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why are you passing that as `text` in the first place? You make the whole function simpler if you just declare the parameter as `timestamp` and get rid of the `to_timestamp()`. Plus: if you use `to_timestamp()` the cast `::timestamp` is useless

Comment: if i declare the parameter as timestamp how should call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is overly complex. You don't need PL/pgSQL and you don't need a (slow) cursor to return the result.

It can be simplified to a plain SQL function which also will be a lot faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.detectselect (i_channelID integer, te_startTime timestamp, te_endTime timestamp)
   RETURNS SETOF detect_inst AS 
$BODY$
    SELECT * 
    FROM detect_inst d 
    WHERE d."ChannelID" = i_channelID 
    AND d."EndTime" >= te_starttime
    AND d."EndTime" < te_endtime
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You then call it:

```
select * 
from detectselect(1, timestamp '2016-01-21 00:00:00', timestamp '2016-01-23 00:00:00' );
```

---

<sup>You should also avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it</sup>